# Adding a UIButton Programmatically to a subview of UINavigationBar and touch events are not registering

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I have a UITableView within a UINavigationController. To make a toolbar at the bottom of the screen that does not move with the table cells, I added a UIView as a subview to the Navigation Bar.

I am then programmatically creating a UIButton to add the this UIView. I added a selector but it is not registering and called the function I set it it to (sendMessage).

```
self.sendBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-100, self.view.frame.size.width,100 )];
self.sendBar.backgroundColor = cloudBlue;
UIButton *sendButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)];
sendButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[sendButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendMessage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.sendBar];
[self.sendBar addSubview:sendButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that you are adding the button as a subview of the "sendBar" but referencing a selector from the main view. There is two things you could potentially do here:

1: Create your sendBar as a custom subclass of UIView, which includes your sendButton as a subview.  Then, create a delegate for your sendBar and have it get triggered inside your main view from the sendBar implementation.

2: Add the sendButton directly to the parent view as a subview, and not to the sendBar.

```
UIButton *sendButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height,50,50)];
sendButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[sendButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendMessage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.sendBar];
[self.sendBar addSubview:sendButton];
[self.view addSubview:sendButton];
```

Also, you'd probably be okay just adding the sendBar to self.view and not to self.navigationController.navigationBar if you are just wanting it to appear on top of your tableView; but I don't know the full scope of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

sendBar frame is not right, try set it to be :

```
CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,100)
```

sendBar is a subview of navigationBar which usually has a height of 64,so you might want to change height 100 to 64.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *right = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,25, 20)]; 
[right setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; 
[right setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imgPhoto"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[right addTarget:self action:@selector(showRightClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:right]; 
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem1;
```

// If you want to set as Right bar button then `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem1`